# Tomcat 5/Java RESTFul Web Services - Accessing a file in a folder

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm building a RESTful web service using the Jersey API and running it on Tomcat5 in Ubuntu. The web service works fine on my machine (I'm running the web service on Eclipse), the problem is when I try to run it on the server. I have to access a file (more specifically a [jdbm2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/) HashMap) and search it for a given word. To access the file on my computer, I just had to copy the folder that contained the file to the eclipse folder. On the server however, the program can't find the folder. The problem seems to be that the desired folder (called MasterHash) is not in the working directory.

I'm thinking the problem has to do with either the web.xml or the context.xml files. The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>NGramSearch_WebService</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>search</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The context.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/usr/share/tomcat5/webapps/NGramSearch_WebService"
path="/NGramSearch_WebService"
reloadable="true"
workDir="/usr/share/tomcat5/webapps/">

</Context>
```

I'm thinking I have to add a resource in the context.xml file, but I'm not sure of how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the IO call you're making to open the file? Could you keep the file in `WEB-INF` and access it from the classpath?

Comment: @user463324 I think I can keep the file in the `WEB-INF`, however I would prefer to keep it a separate folder (I may have to update the file in the future). I'll consider that option as a sort of last resort, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add resource in your *context.xml* to access a file from your web service class.
Just leave your folder (let's call it "yourfolder") under your "WebContent" folder.

Add the following parameter to your web service class:

```
@Context
ServletContext context;
```

Now use the code below to access your folder:

```
File filepath = new File(context.getRealPath("yourfolder"));
```

Comment: I just figured out what the problem is, it has nothing to do with the context.xml or web.xml. In any case, thanks for the answer.